# admin page does not show list_display fields in django?

Tags: django, django-admin

my `admin page` does not show the `fields` listed in `admin.py`.

Here is the `admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from customRegistration.models import ExUserProfile

    admin.site.unregister(User)

    class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
        model = ExUserProfile

    class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
        inlines = [ UserProfileInline, ]
        list_display = ('username', 'email','dateofBirth')

    admin.site.register(User, UserProfileAdmin)
```

I do not see the `username` and `dateofBirth field` on my admin page.

`models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from registration.models import User
from registration.signals import user_registered

class ExUserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    ishuman = models.BooleanField(required=True)
    dateofBirth=models.DateField(required=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user


def user_registered_callback(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    profile = ExUserProfile(user = user)
    profile.ishuman = bool(request.POST["ishuman"])
    profile.dateofBirth=request.POST["dateofBirth"]
    print request.POST["dateofBirth"]
    profile.save()

user_registered.connect(user_registered_callback)
```

Comment: Could you show `ExUserProfile` model definition?

Comment: @alecxe: I have updated